# C#のクラスをC++で読む方法

Tags: c#, c++, c

C++で書いたdllにC#のクラスオブジェクトを渡し、フィールドを読ませることはできますか？

Comment: 過去の質問について、質問をしたまま放置せず、[解決したものについてはマーク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)してください。

Comment: 質問内容・範囲が細かすぎたり広すぎたりすると上手い答えが出てきません。例えばこんな例ならより的確な答えが得られるのでは？[C#からC++のDLLへデリゲートを渡し、DLL側でコールバック（引数=ワイド文字列）](https://qiita.com/yz2cm/items/8bc26f789c3308799aa9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) っつか .NET Framework にはマーシャラというのがあるので

- [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) の構造体 (not クラス) を [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) から使う
  のは比較的簡単（マーシャラがおよそ面倒を見てくれる）
- [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) のクラスを [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) から使う
  のは面倒（考えるべきことが一気に増える：構造体に留めておくこと推奨）
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) のクラスを [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) から使う
  のは限りなく難しい（マーシャラが面倒見てくれないところを全部手書きする必要がある）

ので「 C# のクラスを C++ で読む」のはお勧めしません。オイラなら最初から選択肢に入らないです。

C++/CLI ならまだなんとかなりそうな気もしますが C++/CLI に手を出すくらいなら全部 C# で書いちゃうほうが学習コスト的に安上がりな気がします。